# Preserve decimals when writing CSVs

Tags: python, csv

It seems the when using the writer to write CSV file, the 0s in decimals are automatically left out. For example

```
out.update({movieID:"%.1f" % (round(sum(rating)/float(len(rating)),1))})
for key in sorted(out.keys()):
        writer1.writerow({'movieID': int(key), 'avg_rating': out[key]})
```

I have specified one decimal in writing CSV, my intended output

```
3.0
3.3
```

Actual output in CSV

```
3
3.3
```

Anyways to preserve this value? I also tried quoting=Non numeric

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't something to do with Excel displaying the values?

Comment: Are you opening the csv in a text editor or excel?

Comment: Please show the first lines of the csv file **in text format**

Comment: @roganjosh you are right. Thank you. My mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying this:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['#', 'Salary']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'#': '32', 'Salary': '100.40'})
    writer.writerow({'#': '33', 'Salary': '100.4400'})
    writer.writerow({'#': '34', 'Salary': '101.40'})
    writer.writerow({'#': '35', 'Salary': '105.430'})
```

The following is received, when the file is opened with Notepad:

```
#,Salary    
32,100.40    
33,100.4400    
34,101.40    
35,105.430
```

If you open with Excel, then a possible solution is to import the column with the numbers explicitly as a text.

- Data > Get External Data > From Text

[image]

- Click "Next", and make sure that the column with the numbers is selected. The radio button should be as "Text":

[image]

- At the end, the csv table is imported to Excel as text:

[image]

Note, that the text in Excel is automatically aligned to the left, while the numbers are to the right. Still, the formulas work on the Text, as Excel is "wise" enough to parse them to numbers correctly.

Comment: I open it in google drive, I didn't thought it is different with open them in notepad.

Comment: @AlexWithYou - so the Excel screenshots are not that helpful, but there should be a way to align.